# Laravel Eloquent, Determining Custom Column as Foreignkey in Related Model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

After a research I couldn't find satisfying answer and I'm here. I have a laravel eloquent model relationship as follows;

```
public function modules () {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Module', 'user_modules', 'user_id', 'module_id');
}
```

As default laravel pairs User model's id with user_id column in Module models but I have another column named parent_user_id and I want to pair User model's parent_user_id column with user_id column in Module model. Is this possible and how? Thank you so much.. I hope this will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the definition of `BelongsToMany`:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L149

You see there are more options available to provide to the constructor.

Now that the `$builder` is injected by Laravel, so start looking from model onwards:

```php
Model $parent, 
$table, 
$foreignPivotKey, 
$relatedPivotKey, 
$parentKey, 
$relatedKey, 
$relationName = null
```

You are already defining the first 4. In your case you need to define the `relatedKey`, which you need to set to match your custom id field.